# How to export Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: c++, firefox

I am creating a simple c++ application for bookmark manipulation.

So I need to export bookmark from firefox and read it with c++ but seems that the bookmarks are stored in a folder always different ( for example on my pc this folder is: /larry/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/**bah0ikoo.default**/ )

It should work on any pc so... How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `profiles.ini` in `%HOMEPATH%\Appdata\Roaming\mozilla\Firefox` tell you the path of the distinct profiles that you can start Firefox with.

On Unix systems: `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`